# Twilio API: Can I send a SMS from a user's phone number?

Tags: twilio

I'm looking at the Twilio docs: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133967-Changing-the-sender-ID-for-sending-SMS-messages

It says `When sending a SMS message from Twilio, you cannot set the ‘From’ phone number as a phone number that you do not own in your Twilio Account`.

My question is, how do you "own a phone number in your Twilio Account"? Does that mean I can get my user to opt in their phone number and then add it to my Twilio Account and then send a text message using their number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording there is slightly confusing. What that means though is that the `From` number must be a Twilio number.

You can see a clearer explanation of this in the [docs section for the `From` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-conditional):

> A Twilio phone number (in E.164 format) or alphanumeric sender ID
>   enabled for the type of message you wish to send. Phone numbers or
>   short codes purchased from Twilio work here. You cannot (for example)
>   spoof messages from your own cell phone number.